# Access form checkbox AND OR statements

Tags: ms-access

Recently I started creating a form to filter the database by using checkboxes.

I have the following data:

```
Category  Type   Country  
Fruit     Apple  NL   
Fruit     Apple  SU   
Fruit     Banana NL   
Fruit     Banana DE   
Nuts      Cashew NL   
Nuts      Cashew US   
Nuts      Almond UK   
Nuts      Almond GR
```

Now I build in my form the checkboxes for Fruit & Nuts, for Apple, Banana, Cashew & Almond and for NL, SU, DE, US, UK & GR.

At this moment I use only the OR statement in my SQL script, which works well. But if the user would like to know for example which fruit comes from NL and it marks both Fruit and NL then my output will be everything from Fruit and everything from NL (because of the OR statement).

How should I change my script that the filter is used based on the checkboxes that are checked? In my example: if the user checks both Fruit & NL then it will give the output --> Fruit Apple NL & Fruit Banana NL

Or another example: He wants Banana & Cashew, and gets as output --> Fruit Banana NL & Fruit Banana DE & Nuts Cashew NL & Nuts Cashew US

I hope my problem is clear; if not, do not hesitate to ask for clarification!

Comment: as you have written , 'if the user checks both Fruit & NL then it will give the output --> Fruit Apple NL & Fruit Banana NL' it is correct. what is your expecting result? if you select fruiit and NL from cehckbox and the output is correct.

Comment: you would like to only have Apple and Banana as an output if user select 'Fruit' and 'NL' correct??

Comment: Are you using dynamic parameterized query that references the controls or are you using VBA to build filter criteria? Mixing AND and OR operators can be tricky. If you want to have multiple parameters from same field, that is additional complication. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Comment: Hi Tarun. At this moment the expecting result is not what I get. I expect to get Fruit Apple NL & Fruit Banana NL. But instead I get all records that contain fruit and all records that contain NL. So I would only like to have the rows containing both Fruit and NL as output.

At the moment I use the SQL view to build my script

Comment: Select * from 'YourTableName' Where Category = 'Checkbox_Value1' AND Country = 'Checkbox_Value2'. Have you tried something like this ? add some data what you have tried until now.

Comment: Could we see the SQL you have at the moment?

Comment: Hi Tarun, I have tried what Darren told me below. My dataset contains 6 columns that should be filtered on. I just simplied it in my example so I can understand the principle and apply it to my project.

I will check if there is another way to create this filtering. If you have any suggestions they are more than welcome ;)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you have a form with 2 *Category* check boxes, 4 *Type* check boxes and 6 *Country* check boxes.

It doesn't sound like any of these filter themselves, so it's possible try and return *Nuts*, *Apple* and *UK* which would return an empty table.

I think you'll have to make extensive use of the `LIKE` command so any `NULL/FALSE` values can be converted to `*`.

As a checkbox returns `TRUE/FALSE` rather than `Apple/False` an `IIF` statement can be used to change `TRUE` to `Apple` (you could probably use `CHOOSE` or `SWITCH` instead).

So the `WHERE` clause here says `chkFruit` is either *Fruit* or *anything*.

```
SELECT  Category, Type, Country
FROM    Table2
WHERE   Category LIKE (IIF([Forms]![Form1]![chkFruit],'Fruit','*')) AND
        Category LIKE (IIF([Forms]![Form1]![chkNuts],'Nuts','*')) AND
        Type LIKE (IIF([Forms]![Form1]![chkApple],'Apple','*')) AND
        Type LIKE (IIF([Forms]![Form1]![chkBanana],'Banana','*')) AND
        Type LIKE (IIF([Forms]![Form1]![chkCashew],'Cashew','*')) AND
        Country LIKE (IIF([Forms]![Form1]![chkNL],'NL','*')) AND
        Country LIKE (IIF([Forms]![Form1]![chkSU],'SU','*')) AND
        Country LIKE (IIF([Forms]![Form1]![chkDE],'DE','*'))
```

**Edit:**
Reading your comment below it sounds like you want it to filter by the ticked boxes, or if no boxes are ticked then show all of them (as if all boxes in the Category/Type or Country were ticked).
That could get quite complicated if you have lots of tick boxes.

So each section of check boxes needs breaking down to something similar to below.

```
WHERE   ((
        Category = IIF([Forms]![Form1]![chkFruit],'Fruit',NULL) OR
        Category = IIF([Forms]![Form1]![chkNuts],'Nuts',NULL)
        ) OR IIF(NOT [Forms]![Form1]![chkFruit] AND 
                 NOT [Forms]![Form1]![chkNuts],Category LIKE '*',NULL))
```

The full SQL would be:

```
SELECT  Category, Type, Country
FROM    Table2
WHERE   ((
        Category = IIF([Forms]![Form1]![chkFruit],'Fruit',NULL) OR
        Category = IIF([Forms]![Form1]![chkNuts],'Nuts',NULL)
        ) OR IIF(NOT [Forms]![Form1]![chkFruit] AND 
                 NOT [Forms]![Form1]![chkNuts],Category LIKE '*',NULL))
        AND
        ((
        Type = IIF([Forms]![Form1]![chkApple],'Apple',NULL) OR
        Type = IIF([Forms]![Form1]![chkBanana],'Banana',NULL) OR
        Type = IIF([Forms]![Form1]![chkCashew],'Cashew',NULL) OR
        Type = IIF([Forms]![Form1]![chkAlmond],'Almond',NULL)
        ) OR IIF(NOT [Forms]![Form1]![chkApple] AND 
                 NOT [Forms]![Form1]![chkBanana] AND
                 NOT [Forms]![Form1]![chkCashew] AND
                 NOT [Forms]![Form1]![chkAlmond],Type LIKE '*',NULL))
        AND
        ((
        Country = IIF([Forms]![Form1]![chkNL],'NL',NULL) OR
        Country = IIF([Forms]![Form1]![chkSU],'SU',NULL) OR
        Country = IIF([Forms]![Form1]![chkDE],'DE',NULL) OR
        Country = IIF([Forms]![Form1]![chkUS],'US',NULL) OR
        Country = IIF([Forms]![Form1]![chkUK],'UK',NULL) OR
        Country = IIF([Forms]![Form1]![chkGR],'GR',NULL)
        ) OR IIF(NOT [Forms]![Form1]![chkNL] AND
                 NOT [Forms]![Form1]![chkSU] AND
                 NOT [Forms]![Form1]![chkDE] AND
                 NOT [Forms]![Form1]![chkUS] AND
                 NOT [Forms]![Form1]![chkUK] AND
                 NOT [Forms]![Form1]![chkGR], Country LIKE '*',NULL))
```

I've got a feeling this could be shortened quite a bit but it's starting to hurt my head now.

Comment: Thanks Darren, this is already a bit better, but we are not there yet.

I will try to explain my issue in another way. It is like an excel sheet when you filter on columns. If the first column is category and I would like to see fruit and nuts I can just click on both of them and all records will show. Then I can filter on NL and the records of all fruits and nuts with NL will remain. 

With your script now I am not able to select both Fruits and Nuts to filter because there are no records left then anymore.

There should be this hierarchy in filtering I guess?

Comment: Hi Darren, Thanks for another response. Sadly it did not work out.
With this script if I just select Fruit it does not show anything.
My case is way more complex than my example :)

Maybe the way I approach it is not correct?
I also saw something like a drop down menu with checkboxes but I do not know if this could also be used as filter.

Basically I would like to build the column filters of Excel on one form in Access.