# Using multiple checkboxes to filter in Access form

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am really new to programming and would like to understand how to build up a form that uses checkboxes to filter data.

In my data I have brand names and a few columns (shoes, pants, costs etc) with either yes or no in it.

The form I built contains checkboxes for all these columns which are named ShoesCheck, PantsCheck etc. These checkboxes have a default value of *False* and there is a button that runs a query I made.

In the query I have multiple IIf statements combined with AND to apply the filter like so:

```
[Shoes]=IIf([Forms]![Filter]![ShoesCheck]=False,"*","Yes") AND ...
```

The problem is that if I only check 1 box, there is no output. While I would like to see all records that have a Yes for that checkbox. 
And if I select 2 checkboxes I would like to see all records that have *True* for the 2 checkboxes, regardless what the rest of the data is.

I have searched a lot through this forum, but most things are quite complicated for me, that's why I broke it down in pieces to understand this part first so if you are going to link to another question or answer please tell me how it works first.

I would add my access file, but can't find the attachment button. My apologies.

Full SQL Code in query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Data
WHERE [Shoes]=IIf([Forms]![Filter]![ShoesCheck]=False,"*","Yes") AND
[Pants]=IIf([Forms]![Filter]![PantsCheck]=False,"*","Yes") AND
[Shirts]=IIf([Forms]![Filter]![ShirtsCheck]=False,"*","Yes") AND
[Hats]=IIf([Forms]![Filter]![HatsCheck]=False,"*","Yes") AND
[Costs]=IIf([Forms]![Filter]![CostsCheck]=False,"*",0);
```

Code in button:

```
DoCmd OpenQuery "FilterData"
```

Data:
[Not allowed to place an image so it became a link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5WG7.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access form checkbox AND OR statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53757201/access-form-checkbox-and-or-statements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy method is the old trick comparing the field with itself - which always will be *True* (except for *Null* values):

```
WHERE [Shoes]=IIf([Forms]![Filter]![ShoesCheck]=False,[Shoes],True) AND
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you show some of your code so we know what's happening when nothing shows up when you click only one?

Otherwise, I'll venture a guess.  For the code behind your Submit button, gradually build up the sql code for the underlying query by reading each checkbox status.  So, you could start with the text

```
Select myfield1, myfield2 from mytable
```

If any checkboxes are checked, you could gradually add to the above text with (and I'm paraphrasing here:

```
if chkboxShoes.checked then
    MySQL = MySQL & " where shoes is not null"
endif
```

for the next checkbox you could have:

```
if MySQL <> "" then MySQL = MySQL & " AND " pants is not null"
```

and keep building it up like that.   At the end, you could make that text be the recordsource behind the form.

I'm likely paraphrasing here but.

```
Myform.recordsource = MySQL

myform.requery
```

You'll have to make some changes about not having a where statement if no boxes are checked, but this is how you would build up the code.

Comment: Hi David,
I have added everything I have in my post.
Does this help?

Comment: Thanks for going to that trouble.  I've looked at it, not tried to run it, and I'm thinking it will only bring back results if all boxes are checked.  But I might be missing something.  If you went the VBA route, as in my example, you could build a query that ONLY used checked boxes as parameters.  That way the query might be simpler.  You would just build the sql query sequentially in code, storing in a string, then when done, assign that string to be the recordsource for the form.  That way it only deals with what is selected at a point in time.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM Data
WHERE IIf([Forms]![Filter]![ShoesCheck]=True,[Shoes]="Yes",[Shoes]) AND 
IIf([Forms]![Filter]![PantsCheck]=True,[Pants]="Yes",[Pants]) AND 
IIf([Forms]![Filter]![ShirtsCheck]=True,[Shirts]="Yes",[Shirts]) AND 
IIf([Forms]![Filter]![HatsCheck]=True,[Hats]="Yes",[Hats]) AND 
IIf([Forms]![Filter]![CostsCheck]=true,[Costs]=0,[Costs]);
```

The code works perfectly untill I add the Costs line. If I do not check the box it only shows me the rows that have a number not equal to 0. If I check the box it works correctly showing me all rows with 0. How can I change it so all records are shown when the box is not checked?

The weirdest thing is that if I change the data from 0 to another number, it all works perfectly again. So it has something to do with 0 as data. I just changed all the 0 into free and made the column a Short Text. This solves it for now, hopefully someone knows how I can still keep the column as currency and apply the filter.

Everyone thanks for your help!